# How to exctract all image urls and href value from html string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML string that holds sets of list items. I want to extract the image url and the correspondent href value from `<li></li>` sets and use these values as variables for later.

```
    <img src="./season/123434mango.jpg" width="180" height="148"
         alt="mango season" class="png">
    <a href="/mango/"  class="corners">&nbsp;</a>
```

example of `<li></li>` set:

```
 <li>
            <img src="./season/123434mango.jpg" width="180" height="148"
                 alt="mango season" class="png">
            <a href="/mango/"  class="corners">&nbsp;</a>


                <div class="thumbnail_label">ok</div>


          <div class="details">
            <div class="title">
              <a  href=
              "/mango/"> mango</a>
              <span class="season">2</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="subject">
              <li>read</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-info">
              <li class="location">Europe</li>
              <li class="price">2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: are you using jquery? or pure javascript? also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am using pure javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery then you can do:

```
var data = [];

$($.parseHTML(siteContents)).each(function() {
    $(this).find("img").each(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        data.push({
                     SRC: $(this).attr("src"),
                     HREF: parent.find("a").attr("href"),
                     LOCATION: parent.find(".location").text(),
                     PRICE: parent.find(".price").text(),
                     SUBJECT: parent.find(".subject li").text()
        });
    });
});
```

You can then use the array "data" that contains objects. Each of which has a "SRC", and "HREF" attribute associated with it.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnaRR/) for an example of it in use.

---

**UPDATED BASED ON COMMENTS**

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PF8dr/) example. The key change is instead of looking for "li" you pass it $.parseHTML(siteContents);

Comment: thanks for replies. chris my html source is called code that comes from getjson . could you tell me how i can use your code with my own code variable ?                                                       $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://someremotesite.com/page/&callback=?', function(data){

var siteContents = data.contents; 

//writes to textarea 
 document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;



var start = siteContents.indexOf('<ul class="list">');
var end = siteContents.indexOf('<ul class="paging">', start);
var code = siteContents.substring(start, end);

Comment: Updated the answer to meet your needs.

Comment: many many thanks chris it solved my problem. could you tell me how i can get location price and subject values too ?

Comment: thanks chris but your last jsfiddle doesnt include the update for location anbd price. could you please add them .thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery this will do the trick and will be organized. I updated with a parseHTML.

//Instead of using each, always think about use for, will be faster.

```
    var imagesSourceAndLinkHref = {sources: [], hrefs: []},
    i = 0,
    code = $.parseHTML('<div><li><img src="./season/123434mango.jpg" width="180" height="148" alt="mango season" class="png " /></li></div>'),
    list = $(code).find('li'),
    images = list.find('img'),
    links = list.find('a');

for(i; i < images.length; i++) {
    imagesSourceAndLinkHref.sources.push(images.attr('src'));
}

for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    imagesSourceAndLinkHref.hrefs.push(links.attr('href'));
}

console.log(imagesSourceAndLinkHref);
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdRFp/)

Cheers!

Comment: rafaed thanks but how to feed my variable called code to yours ? my html source is inside variable called code !